# UPDATE and INSERT on duplicated key

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with 1 unique key (type, color), but I want a query that if i am inserting duplicate keys, for example type: type_one | color: red and there is already a row with that, i want to update the row that is already there but still want to insert.

[image]

I want to update the existing row and continue inserting a new row.

**Example**:

[image]

*query*:

`` INSERT INTO `table` (`type`, `color`) VALUES ('type_one', 'red') ON DUPLICATED KEY `color` = NULL ... **CONTINUE INSERT** ``

[image]

Comment: MySQL doesn't offer a command that both inserts a new record *and* updates an existing on.  You might want to consider a trigger.

Comment: is it possible to change the value that is being inserted on duplicated key?

Comment: dear expert @GordonLinoff can we handle this kind of question with my method?

Comment: @NathanSoares . . . Yes, the value can be any expression.

Comment: @NathanSoares do you test my code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume this can help you(I hope)   :

```
create proc checkingduplicate
    (@color varchar(12),@typeone varchar(10))
    as
    if exists (select type, color ,count(*) from 
    yourtable
    group by type,color
    having count(*)>1 and color=@color and type=@typeone)
    update yourtable set color=null where color in (select  color  from 
    yourtable
    group by type,color
    having count(*)>1 and color=@color and type=@typeone )
    insert into yourtable (type, color) values(@color,@typeone)
    else
    insert into yourtable (type, color) values(@color,@typeone) 

go
exec 'red','type_one'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it the PK:  `PRIMARY KEY(type, color)`  This will force `color` to be `NOT NULL`, or you should do that anyway.

Then, instead of storing `NULLs` into color, store `""`.

This still leaves the app question of whether a 'type but no color' means anything.